# Error 411 Calling Internal Connect REST API (Notifications) | Enhanced Domains

Tags: rest-api, callout, notification, connect-api

I am having issues attempting to mark notifications as `read` using the [Connect REST API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.chatterapi.meta/chatterapi/connect_resources_notifications_list.htm?q=notification). The API is being called by an apex class, but is still treated as an external callout. The method is being fire off by **Community users**.

The `GET` method for notifications works without any issues, but firing off the `PATCH` method throws **`System.HttpResponse[Status=Length Required, StatusCode=411]`**.

---

`https://INSTANCE_NAME--SANDBOX_ENV.sandbox.my.site.com/services/data/v56.0/connect/notifications?read=true&notificationIds=qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm123456,qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm123456`

(instance and notification ids are just placeholder)

---

URL has been added to the `Remote Site Settings`, and the `API Enabled` permission given to the users.

Testing with [Postman](https://www.postman.com/) returns the desired results without the 411 error, so I am thinking it is some sort of instance bug?

This is only an issue in certain sandbox environments. Some work, some don't. Sandboxes should have the same metadata, but are running different Salesforce instances (`CS113`: **doesnt** work, `CS75` **does**)

---

### Update 2023/01/23

Looks like Enhanced Domains are the culprit here (somehow). The last working sandbox just had Enhanced Domains enabled and stopped working like the others.

`GET` methods still work without any issues, but `PATCH` methods are still throwing `411` errors. Adding `Content-Length` as suggested throws a `Read timed out` error but silently works under the hood.

Comment: Sounds like the Content-Length parameter is missing in the headers on PATCH request. Can you check that? Also it might be worth checking if the instances are on the same release and patch versions.

Comment: @devkoala looks like Enhanced Domains seem to be causing issues. The last working sandbox broke today. `GET` works fine, `PATCH` is still broken. When adding `Content-Length` (of any length), the query times out and throws a `Read timed out` error. but it silently works under the hood.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it looks like this was caused by **Enhanced Domains**, somewhat.

The base URL was being calculated using `Network.getLoginUrl(networkId)`, which since Enhanced Domains have been enabled doesn't work. Using `Url.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm()` looks to be solving the issue for all request (`GET` and `PATCH`).